# reverse engineering in symfony

Tags: symfony1, reverse-engineering, propel, creole

I have a database. I am trying to reverse engineer using symfony to create schema.yml. I get this error message:

[propel-schema-reverse] There was an error building XML from metadata: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2030 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

I can generate the schema.xml using Creole but run into another problem later:

Cannot fetch TableMat for undefined table: m_country. Make sure you have the static MapBuilder registration code after your peer stub class definition.

This happens when I am trying to add some master data to the table m_country. This happens for all the tables.

Can somebody give any pointers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the create statements for your database?  Do you have stored procedures?  views?  in your database?  Also, what does your schema.xml look like for the 2nd error?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. I found the problem the same day I posted the question here. However, I use creole to reverse engineer my db which gives me a schema.xml, then use a propel command to convert it to schema.yml and then modify it for further use. I still don't know why reverse engineering cannot be done using propel.

No, I don't have any procedures/views in my db. I simply use a db designer to create relational mappings in tables and then reverse engineer to create schema.yml. I am using Ubuntu 9.04 and latest stable GA versions of symfony, php and mysql.